# sonarqube with multiple projects

Tags: sonarqube

I want to integrate multiple projects in sonarqube(Not multiple modules). Is it possible to integrate multiple projects in sonarqube?
When I used multiple comma-separated sources in sonar.sources attribute of sonar-project.properties file, I got an aggregated report. I want to monitor multiple projects, is it possible to get distinguished reports for multiple sources?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SonarQube with multiple projects (Not mulitple Modules)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079226/sonarqube-with-multiple-projects-not-mulitple-modules)

Comment: Please edit your original question and avoid creating duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the commercial Views plugin : http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/

There is an example on how to use it on my blog: http://qualilogy.com/en/your-own-quality-model/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a look on the project https://sq.4smart.cloud/. It allows to gather results from multiple projects in one consolidated report.